# how to animate two things at the same time in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I want to animate 2 things at same time when mouse hovers something.

for example I want to change background color of box1 with id = "box1" and position of box2 with id="box2" when mouse hovers a div with id="trigger".

but I don't want them to animate in a queue, i.e. one after another. I want them to start animating at same time and finish at same time!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just run them in a row, like this:

```
$("#trigger").hover(function() {
   $("#box1").stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#000000' });
   $("#box2").stop().animate({ top: "-20px" });
}, function() {
   $("#box1").stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }); //set it back
   $("#box2").stop().animate({ top: "0px" });                 //set it back
});
```

This uses [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) to animate one way when hovering, and animate them *back* when leaving.  The [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) is just to prevent animation queue build-up.  To animate a color, you'll need either [the color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color), or [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) included as well.

Animations in jquery, [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), [are implemented](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L338) using [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) with a 13ms timer, so they'll happen outside the normal flow...doing them like above doesn't wait for the first to finish, they'll run simultaneously.

Comment: and how i can animate them one by one? (not simultaneously)

Comment: @Mehran -  The *safest* way is to queue yourself, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Cz62t/

Comment: @NickCraver Does jQuery use the *same* timer for animations running in the same time? Or it schedules different timers with separate setInterval calls for each object to animate?

Answer (score 3):

When the first animation starts, the next line of code executes without waiting for the animation to finish.

So to do two things at once:

```
$('#trigger').hover(function()
{
    $('#box1').animate({ ... });
    $('#box2').animate({ ... });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out [jQuery.animate() docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). There is `queue` property:

> `queue`: A Boolean indicating whether to place the animation in the effects queue. If `false`, the animation will begin immediately.

Comment: He's animating individual elements though, and the queue is *per* element :)

Comment: would you please explain more!

Answer (score 3):

While it's true that consecutive calls to animate will give the appearance they are running at the same time, the underlying truth is they're distinct animations running very close to parallel.

To insure the animations are indeed running at the same time use:

```
$('#trigger').hover(function() {
    $('#box1').animate({..., queue: 'trigger-hover'});
    $('#box2').animate({..., queue: 'trigger-hover'}).dequeue('trigger-hover');
});
```

Further animations can be added to the 'trigger-hover' queue and all can be initiated provided the last animation dequeue's them.

Cheers,
Anthony